# Getting (#100) Missing permissions while fetching posts from facebook page using graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i am trying get post from page's feed with all the permission required.

i am using  page admin access with following permissions, (created user access  token using graph api explorer).

```
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_posts
```

I am trying to get post from my page's feed and i am admin of the facebook page
this is my http GET request

https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/act_XXX/feed?access_token=XXX

but still i get this response

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Missing permissions",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "ALlYjKj9b3PFbqtbnmA8hV-"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?